# Matching of Cells to Arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array `A1:A3` {Apple, Banana, Cherry}. Let cell A4 = Apple and cell A5 = Banana. For the array formula `{=A4=A1:A3}`, it returns a TRUE. However, for the array formula `{=A5=A1:A3}`, it returns a FALSE.

I realized that this is because A5, Banana, is not in the top row of the array. Is there a way which I can still match the cell A5 using the `array` function?

Comment: What you are talking about is relative matching in an array. If you select D10:D12, put in `=A5=A1:A3` with CSE you will end up with FALSE, TRUE, FALSE. The second cell (i.e. D11) is TRUE because the second cell in the matching array is the match. This method is rarely used; even less without absolute anchors (e.g. **$**) on the array range.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=isnumber(match(A5, A$1:A$3, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to work by putting

```
=OR(A5=A1:A3)
```

as an array formula, but I can't think of any advantage over using MATCH.